# Mamp PRO No Owner / Permission trouble on Windows (Running Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, windows, mamp-pro

I have setup multiple hosts and everything was running fine until I wanted to deploy my website. All files uploaded via wordpress failed to transfer. I found out they had no Owner. So even me as a user/admin couldnt open them. I have to use powershell command "icacls * /reset /t /c /q" to fix the permissions and finally uploaded them but it doesnt sort this problem in a long term. Could anyone help me find out how to change the Owner with which Mamp saves files? Or is there any work around ? I havent been able to find anything in documentation not the interent.